# Reducing number of ActiveMQ consumers per single machine

Tags: python, activemq-classic, messaging, stomp

I use ActiveMQ for multiple use cases. Recently I discovered that I have too many open TCP connections (ActiveMQ) per machine. The reason is that each machine has multiple ActiveMQ consumers for different use cases.

I was wondering how is it possible to reduce the number of TCP connections, how to reuse single TCP connection for multiple use cases?

[Multiple consumers on multiple machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFKc.png)

On the image, only 4 use-cases are shown but in my situation, it is a much higher number and every consumer uses different credentials.

We are using STOMP protocol and in most use cases it is Python's implementation of STOMP called stomp.py. Different ActiveMQ consumers had been developing by different teams. Is there any library that they can include which will deal with multiple connections problem under the hood?

Comment: You can reuse a single TCP connection by reusing the JMS Connection object in your application (if you are indeed using JMS). How depends alot on the implementation specifics of your application. Some frameworks may use connection pooling, but it varies a lot.

Comment: I am using STOMP protocol and in most use cases it is Python's implementation of STOMP called stomp.py. I forgot to mention that different consumers had been developing by different teams.

Is there any library that they can include which will deal with multiple connections problem under the hood?

Comment: No clue.. but you may want to update your question with this info and tag it with stomp and python to attract attention of relevant developers.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I edited the question and I hope someone has a solution.